# Have I Killed My SAMSUNG TAB 2?

Tags: samsung, odin

I couldnt update my tablet kept getting the message, "Cannot update as this device has been modified."

So I searched for advice on how to fix it. I was told to put in recovery mode by pressing power + volume down, which I did, but when it came on the message on screen was "WARNING DOWNLOADING NEW OS CAN FATALY DAMAGE YOUR DEVICE. Push volume up to continue volume down to cancel."

I pushed up before realizing what I had done. It then said , "Downloading do not turn off tablet." It was saying this for about half hour then went off. Now I cant get it to come on. Is it dead?

Comment: Was the tablet rooted or modded?

Comment: Hold the `Power` button until the device restarts. If it does not work, hold both `Power` and `Volume Down`.